# amCharts 5: CategoryAxis.height() after first datavalidated event

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

## Context

I am trying to replicate amCharts 4 [Auto-adjusting chart height based on a number of data items](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/auto-adjusting-chart-height-based-on-a-number-of-data-items/) with amCharts 5 instead.

Code pens with console logs:

- amCharts 4: https://codepen.io/jackfoo/pen/XWeoNdW
- amCharts 5: https://codepen.io/jackfoo/pen/MWEZKbX

The very first time the callback for the [`datavalidated`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/categoryaxis/#datavalidated_event) event of a [`CategoryAxis`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/categoryaxis/) is executed, [`CategoryAxis.height()`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/categoryaxis/#height_method) returns a value that seems wrong. I don't know if the axis was actually rendered before the first `datavalidated` event. If it was not, then I guess it does not make sense to call `CategoryAxis.height()`.

For information, the very first time the callback is executed, the property [`inited`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/categoryaxis/#inited_property) is false.

## Question

The very first time the callback for the `datavalidated` event of a `CategoryAxis` is executed, what is `CategoryAxis.height()` supposed to return?

Answer (score 1):

amCharts have updated their tutorial now for version 5.

[amCharts 5: Auto-adjusting chart height based on a number of data items](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/tutorials/auto-adjusting-chart-height-based-on-a-number-of-data-items/)

Now the height is set using

```
chart.root.dom.style.height = chartHeight + "px";
```

Some points to note is

> amCharts 5 uses "root element" approach - you create a root element,
> then add actual chart or series objects to it.
>
> ...
>
> amCharts 4 did not
> have a root element, so chart instance was the top element in the
> tree.
>
> ...
>
> amCharts 5 uses Canvas API as its method of rendering, whereas
> amCharts 4 used SVG.

~ [AmCharts 4 and 5](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/migrating-from-amcharts-4/)

The full code is in [their codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/e855679a1387b6cd13df11a8b6e8a2df)... now the datavalidated event is on the series.

```
var cellSize = 30;
series.events.on("datavalidated", function(ev) {

  var series = ev.target;
  var chart = series.chart;
  var xAxis = chart.xAxes.getIndex(0);

  // Calculate how we need to adjust chart height
  var chartHeight = series.data.length * cellSize + xAxis.height() + 
  chart.get("paddingTop", 0) + chart.get("paddingBottom", 0);

  // Set it on chart's container
  chart.root.dom.style.height = chartHeight + "px";
});
```